# Reset/Delete Cookies in VB.NET application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I want to be able to delete the Cookies/History stored in the application, an example of this:

[image]

I have tried a few code snippets but none seem to work, here is an example of 1:

**(1)**

```
        For Each element In Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies))
            Dim deletecookies As New FileInfo(element)
            deletecookies.Delete()
        Next
```

Just wondering if anyone has been able to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is autocomplete, not cookies. It is stored in the browser, not on the server (Your VB.NET code is running on the server and thus is unable to delete it because it is not stored on the server). When visible, press the down arrow and then press delete to remove the selected item.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thanks I did not know this added Autocomplete="off" in my aspx and seems to work. Thanks for your answer.